LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2
I'm working on a rails application which is built on rails version 5.0.2 and ruby version 2.5.8.
The database used for this is mysql2 version 0.4.10. I also installed the mysql service  which is on stable version 8.
When I try to create the database when the command rails db:create I'm getting the following error,
ails aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:13:in `block in run_rake_task'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:11:in `run_rake_task'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `run_command!'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6:in `<main>'

I tried a lot of solution but no luck. any help in this matter is much appreciated.
Note I'm on macOS monterey 12.

Getting db working can be tricky. Unfortunately it's hard to guess what is the specific reason of this type of error unless you have met the exactly same error in the exactly same environment (which I haven't).
Did you check mysql2 issues on github? There is a vast of advises there and I believe some of them should help.
https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues?q=is%3Aissue+cannot+load+such+file+--+mysql2%2Fmysql2

thanks for the reply. I checked the shared link and get to know that mysql version 8.3 is not capatibale with rails and on my macOS enviornment. So, I downgrade mysql version from 8.3 to 8.0 and it is working fine for me.
@peresvetjke
